# Domain of function $\sin^x A + \cos^x A \ge 1$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Given that,
$$\sin^x A + \cos^x A \ge 1$$
$$0<A<\pi/2$$
Then what will be the domain of $x$?

Comment: It's not really a function, is it?  It is an inequality.  You seem to be asking about the region of solutions for $x$ (which may depend on $A$).

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct, you are asking for the function

$$f(x)=\cos^x A + \sin^x A$$

to be greater than or equal to $1$ for all $x$ inside its domain. What should the domain be.

Since $0< \sin A < 1$ and $0 < \cos A < 1$, $\sin^x A$ and $\cos^x A$ are both decreasing function for $x$.

Since
$$\sin^x A + \cos^x A = 1$$ 
when $x =2$

So the domain is $x \le 2$.